# while implementing threading on android the app runs correctly for the first time but then its gives a warning

Tags: android, multithreading

Activity manager:Warning:Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;

public class SplashBmiActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_bmi);
    Thread timer=new Thread()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                sleep(6000);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally 
            {
                Intent i=new Intent(getBaseContext(),MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }

        }

    }; timer.start();

}
```

the application runs correctly for the first time but when I run it for second time(without making any changes in the code) it gives the this warning.  Moreover the second time splash screen is not displayed only the MainActivity opens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Activity manager:Warning:Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front**

> ..its current task has been brought to the front..

You are trying to open application that's already opened and in the front.
Nothing wrong here.
If you still want to run the same application time after time just clean your project in between.

Also if you want your thread to run every time your SplashBmiActivity is become active than move your code from `onCreate` to `onResume` method.
 Check Android Activity life cycle for more information.